# Como adicionar la fila de números al teclado del Android

Tags: android, teclado

En mi aplicación necesito **adicionar la fila de números al teclado del Android**, esto es posible, como lo puedo hacer?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes uno o varios EditText? pues poner el xml de ellos?

Comment: ¿Es un editText o que estas usando o deseas usar?, agrega esa información por favor @W1ll

Answer (score 0):

Si usas EditText en la actividad puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
          <EditText
                android:inputType="textPhonetic"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Agrego además la documentación oficial, esta en inglés pero puede que te ayude como [guía](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style)

Revisa los [inputTypes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType) estas son las constantes pero es muy similar a lo que puedes colocar en el atributo del xml.

Comment: No aparece la columna de numeros